# How to run apps in Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone 8

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Hi there i am a windows phone developer, I am unable to run my apps in the emulator, and it says to run the apps on a physical device. Can anyone help me with that because when I develop the apps in the express blend 2012 the windows phone 7 emulator opens up.
Plz help me in running my apps in the wp8 emulator in the visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the target from device to emulator in the start debugging button.

Answer (score 0):

As @deeiip said, check whether the target is correctly set. 
Else, you need to check if you have a hardware support of the SLAT. That is mandetory for running an emulator. Hyper-V needs that. 
If that's not there, you won't be able to run an emulator ever.

Answer (score -1):

you are needed to check Your System Configuration that it is as per the Requirements of Windows phone 8 Devlopment

For More information Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402563(v=vs.105).aspx)